# Not found. Authentication passthru. (devise oauth facebook)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-facebook

I am setting up the login/registration with facebook (devise), but as other people, I have no luck to make it working. I have read lots of posts and articles from other people and went through the settings several times, but still the same results.

When I click on the "Log in with Facebook" button, I get the message "Not found. Authentication passthru".

It has never went though the "facebook" controller action, but always through the "passthru" action.

I use:
- rake v2.3.0
- rails v4.2.3
- devise v3.5.2

Thank you for any help. 
Miroslav

---

## omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  # You should configure your model like this:

  # You should also create an action method in this controller like this:
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  # More info at:
  # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#omniauth

  # GET|POST /resource/auth/facebook
  def passthru
    super
  end

  # GET|POST /users/auth/facebook/callback
  def failure
    super
  #redirect_to root_path
  end

  # protected

  # The path used when OmniAuth fails
  def after_omniauth_failure_path_for(scope)
    super(scope)
  end

  #def failure
  #  redirect_to root_path
  #end

end
```

## User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable, :validatable, password_length: 6..72, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.rolable.firstname = auth.info.firstname   # assuming the user model has a name
      user.rolable.lastname = auth.info.lastname
      user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
      # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails, 
      # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
      # user.skip_confirmation!
    end
  end

end
```

## devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|  
  config.mailer = 'CustomDeviseMailer'

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
  config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10 
  config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 1.days
  config.reconfirmable = false
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.password_length = 6..72
  config.reset_password_within = 24.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET']

end
```

## routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, path: "auth", :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations', confirmations: 'confirmations', passwords: 'passwords', omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks'}
```

## rake routes

```
user_omniauth_authorize_en GET|POST /en/auth/auth/:provider(.:format)                                                                  omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:locale=>"en", :provider=>/facebook/}
user_omniauth_authorize_ma GET|POST /ma/auth/auth/:provider(.:format)                                                                  omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:locale=>"ma", :provider=>/facebook/}
user_omniauth_authorize_cs GET|POST /cs/auth/auth/:provider(.:format)                                                                  omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:locale=>"cs", :provider=>/facebook/}
user_omniauth_callback_en GET|POST /en/auth/auth/:action/callback(.:format)                                                           omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook) {:locale=>"en"}
user_omniauth_callback_ma GET|POST /ma/auth/auth/:action/callback(.:format)                                                           omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook) {:locale=>"ma"}
user_omniauth_callback_cs GET|POST /cs/auth/auth/:action/callback(.:format)                                                           omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook) {:locale=>"cs"}
```

## login.html.erb

```
<%= button_to t(:login_form_link_facebook), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :title => t(:login_form_link_facebook), :class => "btn btn-fcb full-w capital semi-margin-bottom bold", :method => :get %>
```

Comment: When I remove the line "config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET']" from devise.rb, it takes no effect. same behavior, so I assume something is wrong with that config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was with routes. I was using localized urls and it was causing issues with facebook omniauth.

Instead of:

```
localized do
    devise_for :users, path: "auth", :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations', confirmations: 'confirmations', passwords: 'passwords', omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks'} 
end
```

I used:

```
devise_for :users, path: "auth", :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations', confirmations: 'confirmations', passwords: 'passwords', omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks'}
```